# Setting value of configurable field name in a generic way in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can I set the value of a field like shown below? I have some item-types that have different keys, but I would like to treat one of the fields as a "name", and be able to set the value of the name in a generic way.

If possible I would like to be able to set the type of the "name" so I can use any field, but locking it to a string is also acceptable.

```
interface Thing { 
    name: string
    active: boolean
}

interface Other { 
    handle: string
    count: number
}

interface ItemConfig<T>{
    nameField: keyof T
}

const log = <T,>(item: T, config: ItemConfig<T>) => {
    // This is OK
    console.log(item[config.nameField])
}

const clearName = <T,>(item:T, config: ItemConfig<T>) => {
    // This is an error
    item[config.nameField] = ""
    return item;
}

const myItem: Other = { handle: "test", count: 2 }
const myConfig: ItemConfig<Other> = { nameField: "handle" }
const cleared = clearName(myItem, myConfig)
```

Comment: is this what you've been looking for? `interface Thing { [x:string]: string}`

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar I don't think so, because each interface can be made up of many types. I will adjust the question to make this more clear.

Comment: is it not possible to do `const clearName = <T>(item: T, config: keyof T ) ` directly?

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar No, because the problem is not finding the correct place in the item, the problem is finding the correct type to use for the value to be set. In the code above we can't set a string because the field could be of any type as written. I'm looking for a way to tell the compiler what type it is, and set a value to "zero" the field.

Comment: You cannot guarantee that the value of T will be string only, you can do something like this if you are sure that keyof T will always be stirng, `let value = item[config.nameField] as unknown as string; value = "";`

Comment: Also, you can put typeof condition before you evaluate the above statement to be 100% sure that the value is of type string